# wordpress show gallery if post has a gallery

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gallery, posts

i am new to Wordpress.
Now i am working on the Avada Theme.

Problem:
i wanted to display specific posts on 3 different pages.
So i installed the plugin "list category post" and worked my way through to display what i want.

Everything is working, except the gallery in a post.
I have one post with a gallery. If i open the Post, the gallery is shown. But the plugin dont show the gallery.

Pictures and text are displayed normal.

My snippet looks like this:

```
 [catlist name=Kochkurs excerpt=full excerpt_strip=no class="blogeintrag"]
```

how can i let the plugin also show the gallery??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any galleries on posts in the "Kochkurs" category will be rendered if you add "content=full" to the shortcode:

```
[catlist name=Kochkurs excerpt=full excerpt_strip=no class="blogeintrag" content=full]
```